# Creating Virtual Environment with Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a virtual environment with the following command:

`pyvenv-3.4 venv`

It gives me the following error message:

> The program 'pyvenv-3.4' is currently not installed. You can install
>   it by typing:sudo apt-get install python3.4

This despite the fact that Python 3.4.3 is currently installed on my Ubuntu system.

If i still try the above command, I get the following message:

> python3.4 is already the newest version.0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded

How do I create a virtual environment in Python 3.4 ?

Comment: Possibly related (if you are using Ubuntu 14.04): http://askubuntu.com/q/682612/8005

Comment: Even though it did not explain the weird behavior, that provided me with the solution, and that is what I care for. Thanks